# How do I create a role with AWS managed policy using aws-cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to create an IAM role with AWS managed policy, however it asks me for policy document.

```
aws iam create-role --role-name test-role 
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument --assume-role-policy-document is required
```

I am trying to attach an aws managed policy like `AWSLambdaFullAccess`

Answer (score 14):

Trust policies define which principal entities (accounts, users, roles, and federated users) can assume the role. Every IAM role requires a trust policy.

You have to specify a trust policy when creating a role through the CLI. Identity-based policies (managed/inline) can be attached to a role afterwards by using `attach-role-policy` or `put-role-policy` commands.

The following trust policy lets Lambda service assume this role. You have to provide this file as input to the command using `assume-role-policy-document` option.

**trust-policy.json**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
aws iam create-role --role-name Test-Role --assume-role-policy-document file://trust-policy.json

aws iam attach-role-policy --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambdaFullAccess --role-name Test-Role
```

Comment: uhm, that's weird ! because aws already give us this option in the console management ! you can create a role without any policy and you can attach a policy to it afterward. why can't we do the same with the cli ?!

Comment: that's not right. you have to specify a trust policy in the console too, the first step when creating a role in the console is to select the type of trusted entity, which maps to the trust policy in the example above.